# How to run java service as a non-root user on CentOs 6

Tags: java, linux, centos, startupscript

I have a script that starts java application as a service on CentOs 6.
Here it is:

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: - 80 20

SERVICE_NAME=cn4server
PATH_TO_JAR=/usr/local/share/myserver/cn4server.jar
PID_PATH_NAME=/usr/local/share/myserver/cn4server-pid
case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
        if [ ! -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    stop)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stoping ..."
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..."
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    restart)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopping ...";
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ...";
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME starting ..."
            nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
esac
```

It works well, but there is a problem: it runs as a root.
How can I change the script to run java application on behalf of another user?

Comment: I believe this question belongs on the [Unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) stack.

Comment: Check out cron's `@reboot` shortcut and put it in the respectives user's crontab.

Comment: I tried but unfortunately cron's @reboot doesn't work for non-root user on CentOs. Here is some explanation: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109804/crontabs-reboot-only-works-for-root

Comment: Finally crontab worked. It was my mistake passing wrong arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was:
crontab for a non-root user with the line
    @reboot /usr/local/share/myserver/cn4server.sh restart

It workes fine, although it's a workaround.